# How to make Auto Layout for Universal App

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm now doing an universal app; I faced a problems on auto layout; I need to make two views with same size on all devices; I worked on storyboard with view wAny hAny; and here the images I reach [image]

The problem on iPad the bottom view it's very big and I need these two vies almost same height like on the attached photo for iPhone-4inch

The following photos shown my constrains
The following for top view
[image]
and the following for bottom view
[image]

if i do equal height there's the photo
[image]
and herewith the constrains
[image]
and here the output
[image]

here the modification as you see iPad is problem
bottom view
[image: layout]
[image: topView]
[image: bottom View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the two views to be the same height, give them an equal height constraint, and eliminate the constraint between the bottom view and the top of the superview. You make an equal height constraint by selecting both views and choosing "Equal Heights" from the pin menu. If you want them to not be exactly equal, you can edit that constraint to change the multiplier value to whatever you want.

Comment: i do this but it's not success; if you know special constrain to give for iPad only; coz the main problem on iPad; moreover if i do equal height for both views the bottom view on iPad the height will be more than the upper view

Comment: @user3143330, If you give them equal heights, they will be equal -- if you're not seeing that, then you're doing something wrong. I can't tell what without seeing what you did.

Comment: i make edit for my question; please check and tell me

Comment: The top view should not have a constraint to the bottom of the super view. The top view should have a constraint to the top of the superview, the bottom view should have one to the bottom of the superview, and there should be a space constraint between the two views. Other than the equal height constraint, there should not be any other vertical constraints. You also need to edit the equal height constraint so the multiplier is 1.

Comment: the problem on iPad coz iPad have a big screen; these constrain not matching with iPad; if you know a good tutorial for auto layout for universal app; please advice

Comment: @user3143330 The problem has nothing to to with the iPad. If you add the correct constraints, as I outlined, your views will be equal heights. You should edit your question again to show your latest attempt. There are 3 videos from the WWDC 2012 on auto layout. you should watch those.

Comment: ok; i'll edit my question with the result; can you wait a moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79589/discussion-between-user3143330-and-rdelmar).

Answer (score 1):

On the upper view set left right and top constraint, on the lower view set bottom, equal width, align leading and equal Heights. Set vertial spacing between both views.

[image: Equal spacing]

Comment: the problem on iPad; coz big view; not matching with these constrains; if i can do anything special for iPad ; advice